# CentOS 7.7 not able to upgrade docker-ce latest package

Tags: centos, yum, docker

I have CentOS 7 server with `docker-ce-18.06.1.ce-3.el7.x86_64` install. now I want to upgrade to latest docker rpm. but `yum upgrade docker-ce` not showing the latest package. Any help to fix this issue?

**not listing the latest rpm**

```
yum list docker-ce --show-duplicates
Loaded plugins: copr, fastestmirror, rhnplugin 
Installed Packages
docker-ce.x86_64                                                                      18.06.1.ce-3.el7                                                                       @docker-ce-stable
```

**all repo is enabled**

```
# yum repolist
Loaded plugins: copr, fastestmirror

repo id                                                                              repo name                                                                                       status
base/7/x86_64                                                                        CentOS-7 - Base                                                                                 10,060+10
docker-ce-stable/x86_64                                                              Docker CE Stable - x86_64                                                                           12+67
epel/x86_64                                                                          Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                                   13,335+1
extras/7/x86_64                                                                      CentOS-7 - Extras                                                                                  356+41
google-chrome                                                                        google-chrome                                                                                           3
group_spacewalkproject-nightly-client/x86_64                                         Copr repo for nightly-client owned by @spacewalkproject                                             59+21
nodesource/x86_64                                                                    Node.js Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                                       97
updates/7/x86_64                                                                     CentOS-7 - Updates                                                                                 831+30
yarn                                                                                 Yarn Repository                                                                                        50
repolist: 24,803
```

**This command returning any packages**
`yum --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=docker-ce-stable upgrade`

adding the repo details

```
[docker-ce-stable]
name=Docker CE Stable - $basearch
baseurl=https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/7/$basearch/stable
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/gpg
```

Comment: Not knowing the status of docker-ce in Centos 7 myself, what evidence do you have that there's something newer out there that you're not seeing?

Comment: By the way, you mention that "all repos are enabled" followed immediately by a command that *disables* all repos and enables a single one.

Comment: latest docker-ce package is `docker-ce-19.03.8-3.el7.x86_64`. I have installed it on another server.

Comment: Did you catch which repo it came from? Disabling all your repos seems an unusual step to take if you're trying to install a package. Alternatively, the site/mirror you're hitting just hasn't been sync'd yet?

Comment: its coming fro docker repo. site is working. I was able install it in another server.

Comment: Hmm; the timestamp on that repo shows that file being over a month old at this point -- `"19.03.8-3.el7.x86_64.rpm                                                    2020-05-07 21:54:18 24.5 MiB"`, so it seems something is preventing you from seeing it (as well as some intermediate versions higher than 18.06.1)

Comment: @JeffSchaller thank for looking at this. let me keep exploring this issue.

Comment: Check for `exclude` parameters in your various yum config files.

Comment: thanks for the pointer, my /etc/yum.conf file had exclude list. I used this command to install the packge `yum --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=docker-ce-stable upgrade  --disableexcludes=all docker-ce`

Comment: Glad you found it! Feel free to self-answer, or we can consider VTC as an internal "typo"/misconfig.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found /etc/yum.conf file had exclude list for docker package. I used this command to install the package

`yum --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=docker-ce-stable upgrade  --disableexcludes=all docker-ce`

Thanks